# How to customize JSON response from Rails app using Rabl gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, rabl

In my rails API app Im using the Rabl gem to render JSON. However, I ned the JSON to be in a specific format.

This is the JSON my rails app is sending as a response :

```
  [{"lat":"49.2505","lng":"-123.1119"},{"lat":"49.2515","lng":"-123.1109"}]
```

This is the response the client wants to get

```
  {"photos":[{"lat": 37.775, "lng": -122.4183333}, ...]}
```

Here is the code that renders the json in the file **index.json.rabl**

```
collection @photos
attributes :lat, :lng
```

I tried this code in the index.json.rabl file but the response came out as follows
     collection @photos
     node(:photos) { |photos|attributes :lat, :lng}

```
 [{"photos":["lat","lng"]},{"lat":"49.2515","lng":"-123.1109","photos":["lat","lng"]}]
```

Not exactly what the client needs

What would I have to change in this code to get the correct JSON response for the client.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried `@photos.first`?

Comment: @ethagnawl. Thanks, I just solved this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this:

index.json.rabl

```
 collection @photos => :photos 
 attributes :lat, :lng
```

yields

```
 {"photos":[{"lat":"49.2505","lng":"-123.1119"},{"lat":"49.2515","lng":"-123.1109"}]}
```